# Simple Flask app runs but page will not load

Tags: python, flask

So last night I closed terminal without closing my flask app or deactivating my venv. I think maybe this is the cause of the issue but none of my googling has yielded results.

When I run the flask app I get this in the terminal:

```
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 178-606-161
```

I have the following view function:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

When I try to load the page in a browser I just get a spinning icon. No error page. Nothing. Just a loading icon.

I am running the app inside my venv. I've tried deleting and recreating my venv. It was working fine yesterday, and with no changes it is now not working.

Comment: Can you run `curl -i http://127.0.0.1:5000/` and see if you get a response?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can change a port to run your app.I have encountered the same problem.Maybe the process of port 5000 is still in zombie state?

```sh
flask run --port=6000
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, possibly associated with Docker cleanup I did earlier. Running `curl -i http://127.0.0.1:5000/` doesn't resolve, and port 6000 doesn't work for me, but using 5XXX fixed it:

```
flask run --port=5050
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the port didn't work. I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling Ubuntu. Worked fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

It Happens to me once  I mistakenly duplicate a callback function. So there were 2 callback functions for a single page that have the same inputs and outputs leading to the same situation.